# 12V lead acid battery instead of 11.1V LiPo?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, remote-control

I'm doing research on a remote control model ship. I have 11.1V LiPo batteries, but because of their weight and duration, larger batteries are considered better in this application (these batteries come were originally for RC airplanes, where lightness is key.)

My battery would go to an ESC, then to an electric motor. I have read that true, non-nominal voltages of LiPo batteries are higher, somewhere closer to 12.6V at peak. Because a 12V battery rating is also nominal, I understand it might be necessary to use a resistor or some other means of reducing voltage, but I do not really know much about how current flows, charge rating, cell count, etc.

The ESC being powered would be something [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0832JKL16), rated at 40A, and there would be a [motor like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077HH9B8S) on the end, rated for 2s to 4s batteries. I'm assuming these ratings are just to guide people using standard material. Also, I actually have two ESCs and motors, but they are both plugged through the same receiver.

This would be the normal max power, from what I understand [from this article](https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question501.htm):

```
power = voltage * current
480W = 11.1V battery * 40A ESC
```

Using [this lawnmower battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IICL5A6) for example, this would be the max power output (I think?):

```
420W = 12V battery * 35A battery rating
```

There could be something terribly wrong with this calculation, but it does look like it would work, while supplying a little less wattage, but likely allow a longer use period. Note that I used the amp rating of the battery for the second calculation, since it's lower than the ESC's max tolerance. Again, I could be mistaken. I've heard scary things about the power of 12V car batteries to solder metals together.

So I'm wondering, what arrangement would be needed to power such a system through something like a 12V lawn mower battery? Is that possible, or will this fry my ESCs, motors, and receiver?

Comment: Consider Wh and ESR of battery specs then Use PWM Control in ESC to limit current average.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're asking about "How much energy do the batteries hold" when you're describing power above, yes??   Your equations tell you how much instantaneous power (maximum) the battery can deliver, not how much energy they store.   That's described in mA-hr  (Milliamp-hours) or A-hr  (Amperes - hour) or sometimes W-h.      For example, a 1000mA-hr could provide 1000mA for one hour, or 100mA for 10 hours, etc..    Is that what you're seeking???       Your controller is only looking for 3A output - That's a fraction of what the batteries can deliver.

Comment: @KyleB I'm looking to make sure that the energy output will not fry my electronics. As for milliamps/hour, I'm not sure how many a larger battery would have, but am supposing that it could provide more than my current 1800mAh. The idea here is that an RC ship needs to be weighed down to its waterline, so having a heavier battery is useful.

Comment: Ah - I follow you now.   The ESC is the thing that does the 'controlling'.      Many people new to electronics have misconceptions, and this one of yours is common.  It's not the battery (voltage source) that controls the power flowing in the circuit - It's the LOAD that does.   The source limits the maximum power available, but does not dictate the power delivered.   For example, if you had NO LOAD on the battery (open terminals), the power delivered would be zero, right?    If you short them, the power delivered would be maximum.    The ESC's load has to fall somewhere in between.

Comment: @KyleB As far as I know, the 3A is for feeding the rest of the RC circuit, while some other amperage goes to the motor, so that the vehicle can operate off only one large battery?

Comment: The brushless motor plugs directly into the ESC.   The ESC delivers power to everything else.  Check this block diagram. 
 
 
 
https://ftforumx2.s3.amazonaws.com/2017/06/153867_8e3ef1af05ea12f747b79e9759dd8abc.png

Comment: Don't take that diagram TOO literally of course   ;)   It's just an example.   Refer to the technical data for your actual parts.    And BTW, you are right, a 12V car battery most definitely can "melt metal"  :)   I've seen some (poor) arc welding done with just a few car batteries.

Comment: @KyleB That diagram is exactly the configuration I'm planning on. Note I've done this before, but only for one motor.

Comment: :)  OK -     I got ya.    So really your question is "Can I use a 12V lead acid battery instead of 11.1V LiPo" ?   Sorry it's taken this long to get that into my head   LOL

Comment: Do you have the technical datasheet for the ESC?    There's a characteristic of lead-acid batteries that is very different from LiPo.   As a lead-acid battery discharges, it's output voltage drops.  Whereas a LiPo, the output voltage is much more constant.  I don't know what the ESC would do in that case.   The datasheet might tell you more.

Comment: Comparison of discharge characteristics       https://www.powertechsystems.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/11/LiFePO4-vs-Lead-Acid-Discharge-Curve-EN-300x173.png

Comment: This kind of thing is done, and there is indeed substantial overlap in the ranges of the differently shaped voltage curves of a 6-cell lead acid battery and a 3-cell lithium polymer.  Actually determining if this is workable depends on knowing details of the items which you have not provided.  That is typically the reason why product usage questions such as this are off topic on this site.  You will do better on an R/C boating forum, especially if you can find people familiar with the particular ESC and motors you want to use.

Comment: So the vibe I'm getting is that for any particular setup, I'll have to *try* it and see whether it works (it should)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output voltage from a standard Li-Ion or Lipo battery pack with (3) cells in series (3S) ranges from about 12.6 Vdc (freshly charged) down to about 9.0 Vdc (end of life cutoff-voltage).

A standard 12V Lead-Acid battery ranges from about 14.5 Vdc (freshly charged) down to about 11.0 Vdc (end of life cutoff-voltage.

Best to check the datasheet for the device(s) that you are powering.  However, my past experience says that you can safely substitute a 12V Lead-Acid in place of a 3S Li-Ion or Lipo battery pack.

[Edit]
One thing to consider that Li-Ion or Lipo batteries have **FAR** greater energy storage as compared to a Lead-Acid battery of similar size or weight.  Lead-Acid batteries are significantly less expensive than Lithium technology.  That is one of the few advantages that Lead-Acid batteries have compared to Lithium-type batteries.

Comment: Update: I actually realized that the ESCs I ordered were compatible with 2-4s LiPo batteries, which have a voltage from 7.4V to 16.8V. Therefore, a 12V battery should be well within range.